# how to (define and call events for a child datagrid) within the data grid

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i need to define events for the datagrid with in another datagrid(master child  grid)
**now i need to define events for  child grid and call those events when i click the child data grid**

**i have  define events for child  data grid in xaml page. but these events or not getting fired.** how  should i  go ahead ?
**RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dgrdRowDetail_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"**

is my Xaml code

```
<sdk:DataGrid MinHeight="100" x:Name="dgCounty" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"   IsReadOnly="True"  Margin="5,5,5,0" RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dgCounty_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"  SelectionMode="Extended"   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="24" Height="24" Click="Details_Click">
                                <Image  x:Name="img" Source="Images/detail.JPG" Stretch="None"/>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="ID">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                                <sdk:Label Content="{Binding EmployeeID}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Name">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <sdk:Label Content="{Binding EmployeeFName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="MailID">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <sdk:Label Content="{Binding EmployeeMailID}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgrdRowDetail" Width="400" HeadersVisibility ="None"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dgrdRowDetail_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"  SelectionMode="Extended"   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
                        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn   Binding="{Binding CompanyID}"/>
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Score">
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <StackPanel Loaded ="StackPanel_Loaded" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue"></TextBlock>
                                                                                           <Image x:Name="imgScore" Source ="{Binding Score}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch ="Fill"/>
                                         
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                       

                    </sdk:DataGrid>
                  

                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGrid>

private void dgrdRowDetail_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
           
           {

           }
```

does any one knows how to define and call the events of  child datagrid. any help  would be  great looking frwd for an solution.

thanks in advance

prince

Answer (score 0):

Soution:
 define globally 
**DataGrid dgrdRowDetail;**

in event parent event  we  can fine  the  child data grid and then   define the event for the child data grid to.

```
   private void dgCounty_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
            {            
           dgrdRowDetail = (DataGrid)e.DetailsElement.FindName("dgrdRowDetail");
             dgrdRowDetail.RowDetailsVisibilityChanged+=new EventHandler<DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs>(dgrdRowDetail_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged);
    }
```

**once  you get  your  dgrdRowDetail which is the  child  control then  yoy can perform all the actions against it like binding,events all those stuff.**